# Insert one table into another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two nearly identical tables (without PK I believe), each has slightly different data in, but in the same format.

How do I insert all the data from one table onto the end of the other table? Thus creating one giant table.

Each table has millions of rows.

I have been trying various combinations of

```
INSERT INTO os5birm 
    SELECT * 
    FROM os50birm
```

but I keep getting the following error message:

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

The two tables are formatted as follows:

[image]

And the data inside is as follows:

[image]

Cheers!

Comment: "but I think I need something more complex." Why do you think so?  What was the result of the statement you do not think is complex enough? What is the real problem?

Comment: Sorry for my awfully phrased questions. I have edited with the actual error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are trying to insert the computed value `ogr_geometry` into the computed column of the same name, and you can't insert into computed columns. The solution, which you should really be doing anyway ([Bad Habits to Kick : Using SELECT * / omitting the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)) is to explicitly list the columns you are selecting, and the columns you are inserting to:

```
INSERT INTO os5birm (Column1, Column2, Column3) 
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 
FROM os50birm;
```

Comment: Exactly what I was going to type, if you had not done so.... 

Comment: Thanks so much, that explains a lot!